# How do I hide a parent li-element whose child ul-li elements are all hidden using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, nested, hide, element, show

I have a set of nested ul's that look like this:

```
<ul id="educationList">
    <li class="category"><p>Media production</p>
       <ul>
          <li class="education" style="display: block;">
             <a href="#">Real time 3D animation</a>
          </li>
          <li class="education" style="display: block;">
             <a href="#">Filming with Steadicam</a>
          </li>
          <li class="education" style="display: block;">
             <a href="#">Sound Effects</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The top ul (educationList) holds a list of categories and each category has a sub list (ul) with the educations that sort under this category. A classic nested list structure. In the sample code above I have just one category - in the real code there are a lot of categories.

I have a jQuery filtering function that shows/hides li-elements that have the class "education" (sub list elements). Sometimes this filtering function hides **all** sub list elements, so the HTML looks like this:

```
<ul id="educationList">
    <li class="category"><p>Media production</p>
       <ul>
          <li class="education" style="display: none;">
             <a href="#">Real time 3D animation</a>
          </li>
          <li class="education" style="display: none;">
             <a href="#">Filming with Steadicam</a>
          </li>
          <li class="education" style="display: none;">
             <a href="#">Sound Effects</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The difference is that all sub list elements now all have the inline style **display: none**. All of a sudden I have no real use for the parent li with the class "category" since there are no educations under this category.

Now I'm looking for **a smart way to find all category list items that have no visible child education list items and simply hide the category list item**. I will have to run this function every time that I do any filtering because the filtering will affect the child education list items - some that where visible will be hidden and some that where hidden will become visible again.

Also - I will have a lot of elements so it's an advantage if the code is not too resource hungry. Still, this is not the time to be picky. Any solution will do and I'll have to work on optimizing later.

Thanks in advance!
/Thomas Kahn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the simple and convenient jQuery solution that doesn't completely ignore resource usage:

```
$('li.category').each(function() {
  var $li = $(this);
  if(!$li.find('li:visible').length) {
    $li.hide();
  }
});
```

If you need performance optimization, you could do this instead, which doesn't have the overhead of the `.each`:

```
var categories = $('li.category');
for(var i=0,category;category = categories.eq(i);i++) {
  if(!category.find('li:visible').length) {
    category.hide();
  }
}
```

EDIT: fixed bug in optimized version

Comment: The first of your two examples worked perfect! I have to add a $("li.category").show(); before it every time I run the function thought since hiding a parent automatically hides all children, but after that it worked like a charm. In the second example I had to replace category with $(category) in the if-clause and before the hide command but after that it worked great!

Comment: Your second example fails with .find is not a function of category. You need `$(category)` in place of each `category`

Comment: @jamiec: You are right and wrong. My example doesn't work because of the way i extract the element from the jQuery collection. The right way to do it is however not to rewrap the elements, but to extract the wrapped versions by using `categories.eq(i)` instead of `categories[i]`

Answer (score 5):

This should be as simple as:

```
$('li.category:not(:has(li:visible))').hide();
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/wTKEQ/

If you run it as-is, then the category will be hidden. If you change one or more of the sub-items to `display:block`, nothing happens.

Comment: This also happens to be the most resource intensive way you can do it :P

Comment: Still pretty cool, and I dont suppose there'll be like a thousand of them.

Comment: @Eugene: if you read the question it clearly states there will be a lot of elements and that performance considerations are a plus. When an OP states this clearly, giving him the slowest possible answer is not really cool in my opinion, no matter how one-liners rock your world.

Comment: Very elegant to compress this into a single line. I'm tempted to use it, but will go for a less resource hungry solution. But thanks for sharing this oneliner! :-)

Comment: @Martin - Well spotted on the perf. But do try to back it up with some proof :P http://jsperf.com/menu-elements

Comment: @Martin well yeah i didn't notice that perf is an issue. but one-liners are still cool :)

Comment: @jamiec: jsperf is a joke for stuff like this, sorry. Try it out on a  real website where rendering/drawing is part of it and you will understand. Also, be sure to test it through various browsers across different hardware and OSes. I have been performance optimizing websites for over 10 years and if there is one truth i am sure of then it is that jsperf can only be used reliably to test non-DOM interaction logic like algorithms. For any thing else, it is utterly useless, and typically used as a reference for people who simply don't know any better but think they can score a cheap point.

Comment: @Martin - for {diety} sake lighten up. It was an attempt at a joke, and to proove the point that you were correct. You dont need to go spouting your *obviously superior* credentials :rolleyes:

Answer (score 2):

```
$("li.category").each(function(){
   if($(this).find("li:visible").size() == 0)$(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li.category").each(function(){
if($(this).find("li.education").css("display")=="none")
{
$(this).hide();
}
});
```